# Permission denied when trying to use stockfish chess analysis within google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have downloaded stockfish and places the files within my google drive so it can be accessed within colab however it does not allow me to execute the files and I get a permission denied error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
def stockfish(board, depth):
    with chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci('/content/drive/MyDrive/stockfish-3.13.0/stockfish') as sf:
        result = sf.analyse(board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=depth))
        score = result['score'].white().score()
    return score
```

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/content/drive/MyDrive/stockfish-3.13.0/stockfish'
```

Comment: if you can read it then maybe you have to change privileges for these files. ie. using `!chmod ...`

Comment: maybe first check if you can list files in folders - `!ls -al /content/drive/MyDrive`, `!ls -al /content/drive/MyDrive/stockfish-3.13.0`, etc. OR maybe you didn't mount Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and fixed it by using `chmod` as a comment suggests. On the command line outside the python program,

```
chmod 777 path/to/my/stockfish.exe
```

777 makes the file readable, writable, and executable for everyone with access to it. You may wish to be more specific and use a different code. Then in python this stopped failing:

```
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(path/to/my/stockfish)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash again at the end of your path :

```
/content/drive/MyDrive/stockfish-3.13.0/stockfish/
```